# How to design a DFA for the following language?

Tags: theory, regular-language, finite-automata, dfa, automata

How do I go about designing a DFA for:

```
Σ = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

set of decimal digits.

```
L = {w| The decimal number represented by w leaves an odd remainder when divided by seven.}
```

So far, I have (hand) drawn out seven states (q0 - q6), with the odd number of q states being accepting.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: i don't get the question, isn't that just like asking "is the number even and not divided by 7"?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName yeah basically, so 21 wouldn't be accepted by a state because the remainder is 0. 26 would be accepted because the remainder is 5. 27 won't because the remainder is 6. Etc Etc.

Comment: have you search to know hot to find if a number is divided by 7 in DFA?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I figured it out. It was a lot simpler than I was (over) thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct this in two steps:

1. Construct a DFA whose states keep track of the remainder of w when divided by seven. You can do this by constructing states 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 6 and linking them as follows: if w leaves a remainder of r when divided by 7 and the next digit is d, then you want to end up in the state corresponding to 10r + d (mod 7). This will give ten outgoing links from each state. It will be annoying to compute these links, but you only have to do it once.
2. Mark states 1, 3, and 5 as accepting and everything else as rejecting.

Hope this helps!